# Не понимаю,почему выдается ошибка(django)?

Tags: python, django, веб-программирование

views.py

```
from django.views.generic import ListView,CreateView,DetailView,View
from django.views.generic.edit import FormMixin
from django.shortcuts import render,get_object_or_404
from .models import anime,AnimeSeasons,AnimeSeries,Comments
from django.contrib.auth.views import LogoutView,LoginView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from .forms import AuthUser,RegisterForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User 
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate,login 
from .forms import UserCommentsForm


#работает
class StartpageCreateView(ListView):
    model = anime 
    template_name = 'sitepage/sitepage.html' 
    context_object_name = 'all_anime'

#работает
class LogoutUser(LogoutView): 
    next_page = reverse_lazy('sitepage')  

#работает
class AuthUserClass(LoginView): 
    template_name = 'sitepage/auth.html' 
    form_class = AuthUser 
    success_url = reverse_lazy('sitepage')   
    def get_success_url(self): 
         return self.success_url
#работает
class RegisterUserClass(CreateView):
    model = User 
    template_name = 'sitepage/register.html' 
    form_class = RegisterForm 
    success_url = reverse_lazy('sitepage') 
    def form_valid(self,form): 
        form_valid = super().form_valid(form) 
        username = form.cleaned_data['username'] 
        password = form.cleaned_data['password'] 
        auth_user = authenticate(username = username,password = password) 
        login(self.request,auth_user) 
        return form_valid 

#работает
def SeasonsViewFunck(request,slug): 
    template = 'sitepage/season.html' 
    anime_inf = anime.objects.get(anime_url = slug)
    season_inf = AnimeSeasons.objects.filter(anime_id = anime.objects.get(anime_url = slug).id)
    context = {'season_inf':season_inf,'anime_inf':anime_inf}
    return render(request, template, context)


#так себе работаеты
class SeriesViewClass(FormMixin,DetailView): 
    model = AnimeSeasons 
    form_class = UserCommentsForm 
    template_name = 'sitepage/series.html'
    slug_field = 'slug'
    def get_context_data(self,**kwargs): 
        context = super(SeriesViewClass, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['season'] = AnimeSeasons.objects.get(self.get_object().id)     
        context['series'] = AnimeSeries.objects.filter(anime_season_id = self.get_object().id)
        return context
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse


class anime(models.Model): 
    anime_url = models.SlugField(null = True,max_length = 20,verbose_name = "URL")
    anime_photo = models.FileField(upload_to='media',verbose_name='Фото')
    anime_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50,verbose_name='Название Аниме') 
    anime_raiting =  models.CharField(null=True,max_length = 5,verbose_name='Рейтинг') 
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Все аниме'
        verbose_name = 'Аниме'


class AnimeSeasons(models.Model): 
    anime = models.ForeignKey(anime,on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name = 'Название Аниме',blank = True,null = True)
    season_num =  models.CharField(null = True,max_length = 3,verbose_name='Номер сезона')
    season_photo = models.FileField(upload_to='media',verbose_name='Фото',blank = True,null = True)
    season_raiting =  models.CharField(null=True,max_length = 5,verbose_name='Рейтинг') 
    description = models.TextField(null = True,blank = True,verbose_name='Описание')
    class Meta: 
        verbose_name_plural = 'Все сезоны'
        verbose_name = 'Сезон' 

class AnimeSeries(models.Model): 
    anime_season =  models.ForeignKey(AnimeSeasons,on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name = 'Сезон Аниме',blank = True,null = True)
    series_num = models.CharField(null = True,max_length = 50,verbose_name='Номер Серии')
    link = models.CharField(max_length = 50,verbose_name='Ссылка на плеер') 
    class Meta: 
        verbose_name_plural = 'Все серии сезона'
        verbose_name = 'Серия' 


class Comments(models.Model): 
    anime_season = models.ForeignKey(AnimeSeasons,on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name = 'Сезон',blank = True,null = True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name = 'Автор комментария',blank = True,null = True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True,verbose_name='Дата написания')
    text = models.TextField(verbose_name='Текст Комментария')
    def __str__(self) :
        return self.date
    class Meta: 
        verbose_name_plural = 'Все комментарии'
        verbose_name = 'Комментарий'
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms 
from django.forms import Textarea
from .models import Comments
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm 
from django.contrib.auth.models import User 


class UserCommentsForm(forms.ModelForm): 
    class Meta: 
        model = Comments 
        fields = ('text',)    

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        for field in self.fields: 
            self.fields[field].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control' 
        self.fields['text'].widget = Textarea(attrs={'rows':3})  

class AuthUser(AuthenticationForm,forms.ModelForm): 
    class Meta: 
        model = User 
        fields = ('username','password')

class RegisterForm(forms.ModelForm): 
    class Meta: 
        model = User 
        fields = ('username','password') 

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        for field in self.fields: 
            self.fields[field].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control' 

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password"])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path,include 
from .views import StartpageCreateView,LogoutUser,SeriesViewClass,AuthUserClass,RegisterUserClass,SeasonsViewFunck,SeriesViewClass

urlpatterns = [
    path('',StartpageCreateView.as_view(),name = 'sitepage'),
    path('logout/',LogoutUser.as_view(),name = 'logout'),
    path('auth/',AuthUserClass.as_view(),name = 'Auth'),
    path('register/',RegisterUserClass.as_view(),name = 'Register'),
    path('<slug:slug>/',SeasonsViewFunck,name='SeasonPage'),
    path('<slug:slug>/<int:season_num>',SeriesViewClass.as_view(),name='SeriesPage'),
]
```

ошибка: 
[image: ошибка]
Почему выдаётся ошибка и как её исправить?
И как можно сделать код лучше(я совсем новичок)?
Спасибо)

Comment: Покажите больше трейсбека – из этого скриншота не видно, где произошла ошибка в вашем коде.

Comment: @Айванф [ссылка](https://skr.sh/s2J1499FLej?a)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В классе `SeriesViewClass` [поле `slug_field`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.slug_field) должно содержать имя поля связанной модели (`model = AnimeSeasons`), к которой будет матчиться `slug_url_kwarg`. В классе `AnimeSeasons` нет поля `slug`, вот и ошибка!

Как решить? Укажите имя какого-то поля класса `AnimeSeasons` с уникальным значением. Судя по всему, пока что у вас такого нет кроме стандартного `pk`.

---

Помимо прочего, у вас вероятно проблема в этой строке:

```
context['season'] = AnimeSeasons.objects.get(self.get_object().id)
```

Метод [`.get(**kwargs)`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.get) принимает набор именованных аргументов, а вы даёте просто какой-то айдишник. Да и с точки зрения логики, вы берёте объект, потом его айдишник, потом ищете этот же объект по айдишнику... Зачем? Хватит просто `context['season'] = self.get_object()`

---

Далее насчёт улучшений. Эта строчка излишне сложная:

```
season_inf = AnimeSeasons.objects.filter(anime_id=anime.objects.get(anime_url=slug).id)
```

Используйте [`related_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name):

```py
class AnimeSeasons(models.Model): 
    anime = models.ForeignKey(anime,
        related_name='seasons', verbose_name='Название Аниме',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    ...
```

Теперь из объектов класса `anime` можно легко получать соответствующий `AnimeSeasons`:

```
season_inf = anime.objects.get(anime_url=slug).seasons.get()
```

---

По стилю кода:

- Названия классов должны следовать [CamelCase](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) – класс `anime` стоит переименовать.
- Слишком длинные строки надо разбивать на части. Например, как выше в `AnimeSeasons`.
- В списке аргументов пробелы сбоку от знака равно не пишутся.
- А вот после запятых ставить пробел надо.

Comment: @Айванф Спасибо огромное)))))

Comment: @НикитаСеливёрстов На этом сайте благодарность выражают стрелкой вверх и галкой принятого ответа :)